# Optimize creation of a nested hash from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have about 12,000,000 products in a table and looking to build a nested hash in Rails. I output this as JSON to clients.

The table only has a few columns: date_time, country, category1 through 3

Currently I am doing this:

```
      products = Product.where("date_time > now()").select(:date_time, :country, :category1, :category2, :category3).group(:date_time, :country, :category1, :category2, :category3).order("date_time asc")
      products.collect{ |m | m.category1 }.uniq.collect{ |s| {
          :category1 => s, :active => false,
          :category2s => products.select{ |l| l[:category1] == s }.collect{ |l| l[:category2] }.uniq.collect{ |l| {
              :category1 => s,
              :category2 => l, :active => false,
              :country => (products.select{ |lc| lc[:category1] == s && lc[:category2] == l }.first[:country] rescue nil) || 57,
                :category3s => products.select{ |e| e[:category1] == s && e[:category2] == l }.uniq.collect{ |e| {
                  :category1 => s,
                  :category2 => l,
                  :category3 => e[:category3], :active => false,
                  :date_time => (products.select{ |mc| mc[:category1] == s && mc[:category2] == l && mc[:category3] == e }.first[:date_time] rescue nil) || ""
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Loading the products takes about 25ms which is OK, but generating the hash takes about 15-20 seconds depending load and whatnot.

What's the best way to speed this up?

Comment: I've been able to save some 5s by converting the array of Products into a hash right after loading from the database. Turns out working with objects was a significant bottleneck. Still looking for tips though, I'd like to get this to generate the "tree" in under 2 seconds. Also looking at sorting the arrays in memory so I can play with bsearch, not sure if it's worth it though as what I save from selecting might be spent on sorting.

Comment: so many nested queries - can you show us what your JSON output looks like please.

Comment: had a similar problem, retrieving large amounts of orders from an eshop (so having nested queries for users, products, variants, etc… for every single orders). Ended up going redis. Defined a after_save on the product model, which store a json structure (could be a hash) for each product. You then get a blazing fast retrieval. That is not solving your speed problem per product though, but i don't think there's any black magic to expect right here

Comment: I am also caching this (memcached) but must refresh it every hour or so. This means that every now and then an user will get stuck for some 15 seconds when hitting the page. So I'm now trying to see if there's a way to improve the actual algorithm that builds the hash from the DB output, as i've already denormalized the data model, optimized the table and so on.